# ruby multiline grep in file

Tags: ruby, grep, multiline

I'd like to find all cases where a c++ method doesn't end with "NULL);" (any number of spaces between the NULL and the ) and the ; should still let it match).

my code is:

```
Dir['**/*'].select { |f| File.file?(f) } .map {
   |file| a=File.open(file).read 
   puts a.grep(/begin((?!NULL\s*\)\s*;).)+;/m)
}
```

I'd like it to match lines like:

```
begin

anything in here but a paren any number of spaces semicolon
);
```

but not match

```
begin 
somestuff that doesn't matter NULL);
```

and not match

```
begin 
somestuff that doesn't matter 
NULL);
```

The problem is that my code currently only matches single lines.

Rubular for it is here:
http://rubular.com/r/Ex9kmQLecH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing a hacky solution, I never could get the multiline stuff to work.

```
Dir['**/*'].select { |f| File.file?(f) } .map {
   |file| a=File.open(file).read 
   a.gsub("\n"," ")
   a.gsub(";",";\n")
   puts a.grep(/begin((?!NULL\s*\)\s*;).)+;/)
}
```